# JQuery UI dialog - Keeps in front after closing (only in Chrome)

Tags: cross-browser, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a JQuery UI dialog. In IE it works ok but in chrome it doesn't. When I close the dialog using the X button it is like the dialog is still in front of my form: it is impossible to click on the buttons placed where the dialog were displayed.

It is happening to me in all my JQuery UI dialogs, no mather if I handle the close event and remove or destroy the div.

Its like each time I close a dialog, a transparent div remains in the page like this:

```
<div class="ui-effects-wrapper" style="font-size: 100%; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: transparent; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; border-image: initial; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 306px; float: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; top: 188px; left: 479px; bottom: auto; right: auto; height: 156px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; "></div>
```

Do you know what could be causing this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I found that in IE the div that remains after dialog is closed, has different style attributes that the one left on Chrome:

```
<div class="ui-effects-wrapper" style="z-index: 1000; border-bottom: medium none; position: absolute; border-left: medium none; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 307px; bottom: auto; padding-right: 0px; background: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; float: none; height: 158px; font-size: 100%; overflow: hidden; border-top: medium none; top: 87px; right: auto; border-right: medium none; padding-top: 0px; left: 477px;" sizset="0" sizcache0641017125275892="0"/>
```

In IE it has:

```
background: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%;
```

while in chrome it has different attributes:

```
background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Have you checked if there are any javascript errors?

Comment: @AndreLoker Yes, but chrome console doesn't shows any errors. Furthermore, like I said, it works Ok on IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moment I almost said "forget chrome, this app is IE only". Fortunately now I can say hell no to that sick nonsense.

The solution was to comment the *show: "blind"* option. Hope this helps someone:

```
$("#divAlmostWentCrazy")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            //show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
            modal: true,
            title: "Title"          
            });
```